# Random Process derived from Markov process

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have a query on a Random process derived from Markov process. I have stuck in this problem for more than 2 weeks.

Let  $r(t)$  be a finite-state Markov jump process described by 
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\lim_{dt\rightarrow 0}\frac{Pr\{r(t+dt)=j/r(t)=i\}}{dt} & =q_{ij}
\end{alignat*}
when $i \ne j$, and where $q_{ij}$ is the transition rate and represents the probability per time unit that $r(t)$ makes a transition from state $i$ to a
state $j$. Now, let $r(\rho(t))$ be a random process derived from $r(t)$ depending on a parameter $\rho(t)$, which is defined by
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{d}{dt}\rho(t)=f(r(\rho(t))),\qquad\rho(0)=0
\end{alignat*}
Here $f(.)$ is a piecewise continuous function depending on $r(\rho(t))$
with range space as $\mathbb{R}$, a set of Real numbers. In this case can we describe the random process $r(\rho(t))$ as
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\lim_{dt\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathrm{Pr}\{r(\rho(t+dt))=j/r(\rho(t))=i\}}{\rho(t+dt)-\rho(t)}  =q_{ij},\qquad i\ne j\\
\end{alignat*}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but what is asked from you is to note that $\rho(t+s)-\rho(t)=\rho'(t)s+o(s)$ when $s\to0$. Using the ODE defining $\rho$, this is $f(r(\rho(t)))s+o(s)$. Conditioning on $r(\rho(t))=i$, this is $f(i)s+o(s)$. Thus, the process $(x(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ defined by $x(t)=r(\rho(t))$ is a finite-state Markov jump process with transition rates
$$
\lim_{s\to0+}\frac{\Pr(x(t+s)=j\mid x(t)=i)}{s}=q_{ij}f(i).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However I have a small question. Supposed that $x(t)$ is a finite state random process, but not necessarily a Homogeneous Markov jump process (and not even following the Markov property). In this case, can we describe transition rates for the process $x(t)$??? Or what I mean is "Do transition rates are defined only for random processes which follow Markov property?"

Comment: In the present case $x$ is a Markov process. In general the limits in the LHS may exist even when the process is not Markov, then transition rates do exist, but they may not be sufficient to characterize the distribution of the process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.